Asymptotic behavior of weighted sums involving the fractional part function
Currently, I am studying the asymptotic behavior of sums of the form
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}\tag{1}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(n-k) \left\{ \frac{n}{k} \right\}
\end{equation}
In this context, based on limited computations (up to $5-6$ digits), it seems that the following limit might equal $\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}$:
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}\tag{2}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(  \zeta(2) n +\log(n) - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^{-3} \left\{ \frac{n}{k} \right\} \right)
\end{equation}
My approach so far has been to try to evaluate this limit using the following formula, valid for any positive integer $j>0$:
\begin{equation}\label{eq3}\tag{3}
I(j):=\int_{0}^{1} t^{j} \left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\} \, dt = \frac{1}{j} - \frac{\zeta(j+1)}{j+1}
\end{equation}
where $I(0)=1-\gamma$ (with $\gamma$ being the Euler-Mascheroni constant).
This seems natural when considering the development:
\begin{equation}\label{eq4}\tag{4}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{i \geq 0} \frac{(i+1)(i+2)}{2}x^i
\end{equation}
By splitting the sum over $i$ and interchanging sums for $i \leq m$, I've established:
\begin{equation}\label{eq5}\tag{5}
\sum_{i=0}^m \frac{(i+1)(i+2)}{2}I(j) = \frac{m}{2} + \log(m) - \frac{1}{2}\zeta(2) + o(1)
\end{equation}
However, I'm unable to bridge the gap between these intermediate results and the original limit.
I would appreciate:

Any insights on how to proceed from here or elsewhere!
References related to the asymptotic behavior of sums of type \eqref{eq1}
Suggestions for alternative approaches to prove the conjectured limit

PS : This question is part of a more general conjecture for integer values $m \geq 3$. Namely, I conjecture that the following limit exists:
$$
C(m) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \log(n) + \sum_{k=2}^{m-1} \zeta(k) n^{k-1} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^{-m} \left\{ \frac{n}{k} \right\} \right)
$$
I suspect that $C(3) = \frac{\zeta(2)}{2}$, but I currently have no idea for $m \geq 4$. Understanding the case $C(3)$ could provide valuable insights toward addressing this broader conjecture.
Moreover, if this conjecture holds, I would like to know if there exist constants $\theta_m$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^{-m} \left\{ \frac{n}{k} \right\} = \sum_{k=2}^{m-1} \zeta(k) n^{k} + n \log(n) - C(m) n + O\left(n^{\theta_{m}}\right).
$$
Through numerical experiments with $ m=3$ and assuming $C(3) = \frac{\zeta(2)}{2}$, it seems that $\theta_3 =1/2$ works and even $\frac{1}{4} + \epsilon$ might be suitable. This is reminiscent of the Dirichlet divisor problem, which seeks the optimal $\theta$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\{ \frac{n}{k} \right\} = \left(1 - \gamma\right) n + O\left(n^{\theta}\right).
$$
My guess is that $\theta_m=1/4+\epsilon$ is also the optimal value for all $m\geq3$.
PS 2 We can formulate a broader conjecture by considering the following four sums defined for integers $ m \geq 0 $:
$$
S_{m}(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right)^{-m} \left\{ \frac{n}{k} \right\}
$$
$$
T_{m}(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{k-1} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right)^{-m} \left\{ \frac{n}{k} \right\}
$$
$$
U_{m}(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right)^{-m} \left\Vert \frac{n}{k} \right\Vert
$$
$$
V_{m}(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{k-1} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right)^{-m} \left\Vert \frac{n}{k} \right\Vert
$$
where $ \{x\} $ denotes the fractional part of $ x $, and $ \|x\| $ denotes the distance to the nearest integer.

Conjecture
If $\theta $ denotes the optimal exponent in the error term of the Dirichlet divisor problem, which corresponds to:
$$
S_{0}(n) = \left( 1 - \gamma \right) n + O\left(n^{\theta}\right),
$$
then the following results hold:
For $ S_{m}(n) $:

$ S_{1}(n) = n + O\left(n^{\theta}\right) $,
$ S_{2}(n) = n \log n + n + O\left(n^{\theta}\right) $,
For $ m \geq 3 $:
$$
  S_{m}(n) = \sum_{k=2}^{m-1} \zeta(k) n^k + n \log n - C_{m} n + O\left(n^{\theta}\right),
  $$
where thanks to H. Cohen we have the conjectured value:
$$
  C_{m} = \frac{1}{m-1} \sum_{k=2}^{m-1} \binom{m-1}{k} \zeta(k) + \sum_{k=2}^{m-2} \frac{1}{k}.
 $$


For $ T_{m}(n) $:

$T_{0}(n) = O\left(n^{\theta}\right) $,
$T_{1}(n) = O\left(n^{\theta}\right) $,
For $ m \geq 2 $:
$$
  T_{m}(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \eta(k) n^k + O\left(n^{\theta}\right),
  $$
where $\eta(k)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j^k}$.


For $U_{m}(n) $:

$U_{0}(n) = \log\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)n + O\left(n^{\theta}\right) $,
$ U_{1}(n) = \log(2) n + O\left(n^{\theta}\right) $,
$ U_{2}(n) = n \log n - K_{2} n + O\left(n^{\theta}\right) $, with $ K_{2} = -0.4324\ldots $,
For $m \geq 3 $:
$$
  U_{m}(n) = \sum_{k=2}^{m-1} \zeta(k) n^k + n \log n - K_{m} n + O\left(n^{\theta}\right),
$$
where $K_{3} = 1.9538\ldots , K_{4} = 4.9367\ldots $, etc.


For $V_{m}(n)$:

$ V_{0}(n) = O\left(n^{\theta}\right) $,
$V_{1}(n) = O\left(n^{\theta}\right) $,
For $m \geq 2 $:
$$
  V_{m}(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \eta(k) n^k + O\left(n^{\theta}\right).
 $$

Remark: $T_m(n)$ and $V_m(n)$ behave similarly. $S_m$ and $ U_m $ are almost similar, differing only by the constants $C_m$ and $K_m$.

I managed to find a good guess for $C(4)$: $$C(4)=\dfrac{\zeta(3)}{3}+\zeta(2)+\dfrac{1}{2}$$ Thus probably $C(m)$ is a simple linear combination of 1 and $\zeta(k)$ for $k<m$.

Not an answer but a conjectural answer for the value of $C(m)$ supported by
extensive numerical evidence:
$$C(m)=\dfrac{1}{m-1}\sum_{2\le k\le m-1}\binom{m-1}{k}\zeta(k)+\sum_{2\le k\le m-2}\dfrac{1}{k}$$
For instance $C(3)=\zeta(2)/2$, $C(4)=\zeta(3)/3+\zeta(2)+1/2$,
$C(5)=\zeta(4)/4+\zeta(3)+3\zeta(2)/2+5/6$.

Very nice! I encountered binomials in another conjecture that is probably more accessible. This is probably known but I haven't found any references. If for any integer value $\lambda \geq 0$ we have:
$$C_{\lambda}(j) := \sum_{i \geq 0} f(i)i^{\lambda+j}$$
converges, then through experimentation I discovered that for any $n_0 \geq 1$ the following asymptotic formula holds:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(n-k) \left{\frac{n}{k}\right}^{\lambda}= \sum_{j=0}^{n_0} \frac{1}{n^{\lambda+j}} \binom{\lambda-1+j}{\lambda-1} C_{\lambda}(j) + O(n^{-n_0-1})$$

Let  $$S_m(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{k-1} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^{-m} \left{ \frac{n}{k} \right}$$  then I claim that:$$S_0(n) = O\left(n^\theta\right)$$, where $\theta = \frac{1}{4} + \varepsilon$ is the conjectured optimal value (similar to the Dirichlet divisor problem).
$$ S_1(n) = O\left(n^\theta\right)$$  And in general for $m\geq2$
$$S_m(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \eta(k)n^k + O\left(n^\theta\right)$$
where $ \eta(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$. For instance $$S_4(n) = \frac{3}{4}\zeta(3)n^3 + \frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)n^2 + \log(2)n + O\left(n^\theta\right)$$.

The fact that $\theta$ is the same in my previous comment seems to be due to the conjectured relation $$S_{m+1}(n)-S_{m}(n)=\eta\left(m\right)n^{m}+O\left(1\right)$$  for $m\geq0$.
